# How to retrieve ActorRef using Akka.system

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2

Finding a reference to a child Actor from within the context of another Actor is straight forward using something like the following:

```
val foo = context.child("foo") match {
    case None     => createFoo
    case Some(c)  => c
  }
```

The problem I have is I'm creating my first Actor from within my controller using `Akka.system` and it looks like this:

```
 val myActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor(anId)), s"id-${anId}")
```

Now when my controller gets called multiple times, it keeps trying to create the same actor, which is clearly wrong. This will throw an exception. I don't have a `context` in this case since the Controller is not an Actor in itself.

How do I get back my reference using Akka.system? It seems Akka.system.actorFor is deprecated and no longer recommended in 2.2.0 (I'm using Scala).

Is there a way to write a `match {}` clause to get back MyActor for a supplied id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use actorSelection. It is a bit complicated to use, though. I find the easiest way is to keep track of the actorRefs you create. Basically you create your actorRef once (during initialization of your controller for example) and store it as a val.

If this does not work for any reason, you can still look up the actor using actorSelection. The actor has to be created first though in order to be retrieved by actorSelection. ActorSelection can look up the actor by the path, and returns an ActorSelection object, which you can send an Identify message to. There is a resolveOne method which will return you a Future with the ActorRef which is much simpler to use, but I think it is only available in Akka 2.2.1. [Here is the documentation for actorSelection](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection)

Comment: Child Actors are added within the context of the parent, not in the controller.. so having access to a val in the controller to a child is not really feasible unfortunately

Comment: Passing the actors from the parent to the controller is also not feasible I presume? in that case you will need to use actorSelection. It is not the simplest concept in Akka, but it works fine.